# Scala conversion long to datetime

Tags: scala, slick

I am using nscala-time (wrapper for Joda Time) and slick for a project. I'm trying to use this clause to write a line to the database:

```
Article.insert(0,"title1", "hellothere", DateTime.now.getMillis.asInstanceOf[Timestamp])
```

Apparently Slick does not support "dateTime" type defined in Joda Time, and I have to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead. So I decide to do a little conversion inside the `insert` method, using "asInstanceOf". Unfortunately, Scala quickly tells me that Java.Long cannot be converted to Java.sql.Timestamp. Then I used this:

```
 val dateTime = new DateTime();
 val timeStamp = new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());

 Article.insert(0,"title1", "hellothere", timeStamp)
```

This magically works, and all I'm left with is confusion.

How can I convert it one way but not the other? Should I use a different conversion than `asInstanceOf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand what `asInstanceOf` does: **`asInstanceOf` doesn't convert anything**. What it does is *lie* to the compiler, telling it to believe something instead of going with the knowledge it has.

So, you had a `Long`, and then you got a `Long`, but pretended it was a `Timestamp`, which obviously doesn't work.

I have a simple recommendation regarding `asInstanceOf`: never use it.

Comment: emmm..then what is the preferred way of type conversion in Scala, or is there any? (Regarding to my problem)

Comment: @WindDweller There isn't really any type conversion, aside from some stuff on the basic value classes (`Int`, `Double`, `Char`, etc). Either the source object has a method that converts it to something else (like, say, `toInt`), or the target type has a constructor that takes an object of the source type as argument.

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic about it. Your first statement:

```
DateTime.now.getMillis
```

is a `Long`. A Long is not a `Timestamp`, so it makes sense that you can't convert it to one by using `asInstanceOf`.

The second statement:

```
new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis())
```

is using the `Timestamp` constructor to create a new Timestamp instance based on the `dateTime.getMillis`.